# How to add required no.of days to a date consider a count in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a start date and a count of files.Now the end should be depends on the count. For example, i have 40 files to be executed and start date is 01-Jul-17, 
the end should be committed by considering this 40.
If condition exceeds more than 20 then the date should be added with 1.
so for this the result i should get is 02-Jul-17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In A1 cell**

```
01-Jul-17
```

**In B1 Cell**

```
25
```

**In C1 Cell**

```
=IF(B1>20,A1+1,A1)
```

Or

```
=IF(B1>20,WORKDAY(A1,1),A1)
```

To take care of Weekly holidays.

Comment: i have done and got answer. But i have to consider only working days.

Comment: Edited the answer post to take care of your weekly holidays issue.

Comment: Thanks@Sixthsense

Answer (score 0):

@Sixthsense's answer works absolutely. But you can use the `WORKDAY.INTL` function to have more control over the weekends,

```
=WORKDAY.INTL (start_date, days, [weekend], [holidays])
```

Following are the [weekend] options that you could use,

```
1 (default) Saturday, Sunday
2 Sunday, Monday
3 Monday, Tuesday
4 Tuesday, Wednesday
5 Wednesday, Thursday
6 Thursday, Friday
7 Friday, Saturday
11 Sunday only
12 Monday only
13 Tuesday only
14 Wednesday only
15 Thursday only
16 Friday only
17 Saturday only
```